# golang: difference between var b Buffer and bytes.Buffer{}

Tags: go

```
var b bytes.Buffer // A Buffer needs no initialization.


b := bytes.Buffer{}
```

What is the difference between these 2?
I tried here: http://play.golang.org/p/lnkkULeIYm
didn't see difference.
Thanks,

Comment: There is none. Similarly `b := []byte{}` is `var b []byte`--I often prefer the `:=` syntax wherever I can use it (which is not everywhere, as OneOfOne notes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:=` is the shorthand syntax of `var`, in that case b is a zero-valued `bytes.Buffer`.

```
var b bytes.Buffer // is the same as
var b = bytes.Buffer{} // is the same as 
b := bytes.Buffer{}
```

You can't use the short hand version outside functions, so for a global variable you have to use `var`.

From http://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new.
>
> As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.